# JDBC - Generic way of dealing with different objects in single transaction?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

So I have Object `A` and `B` that I want to commit to the database in a single transaction. It seems easy as it is just a matter of `setAutoCommit(false)`. However, since they are different objects, they come from different classes of the database layer (and hence, different methods).

I could try:

1. Creating a new method that instantiate the database classes and pass
   around a connection parameter (inspired by [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/163599) answer to the question "How to manage 2 DAO methods in a single transaction?"). While I love its generic approach, but if
   `dataLayerForObjectA.class` handles queries pertaining to `Object A`
   while `dataLayerForObjectB.class` handles `Object B`, where would
   this method that handles both belong to then?
2. Adopting **Unit of Work** pattern, which I'm not even sure if I should
   be looking at this in the first place, because every examples I can
   find are all .NET framework. I tried to follow, but realized it
   ultimately leads to the same issue as above when the data reaches
   the database layer. All examples I find are just dealing with
   transactions of the same Object.
3. Violating design principles by chunking everything in either 1 of the
   classes, or creating new classes for different combinations of
   objects. I don't want to resort to these.

It's likely I've overlooked certain things as most concepts are new to me, but in short, this is the same trouble I'm facing for the various approaches I looked at - the code doesn't belong to existing classes when keeping in mind of the **Single Responsibility Principle**, and that creating new classes for different kinds of combinations seems wrong.

**UPDATE:** Things seem to fine (for now) following Aseem Bansal's answer. Will update again if I encounter any issue in the future with his approach. Meanwhile I am open to any other kinds of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you have `SalesPerson`, `Customer` as your `A` and `B`. Now if you want to add a `SalesPerson` to the system you can use something like `salesPersonService` and if you want to add a new `customer` then you can use something like `customerService`. From your question you are clear till this point.

Now if you want to add an `Order` to the system, you will need to add two database objects.

I am assuming that you have a separate mapping table which maps the three tables. There can be one table but let's go with a separate table for our example.

Now ask yourself if you want to do this what is the logical `xxxService` for adding orders to the system? `ordersService`. If that requires something like

```
create connection
create order and order mapping
do stuff
commit/rollback
```

Then that is the logical thing to do and so the answer is 3 but that does not violate design principles. It is the logical solution to the problem statement and thus not an issue.

Comment: Sorry that my question is not clear enough. But `A` and `B` is all I have. There's no `C` (in your example, `Order`). The relation is simply that if A exists, then at least one B belonging to A must exist. So if A is added but adding B fails, then we must rollback A.

Comment: @DxHito Same logic applies. Adding A means B must be there. So place the logic in A.

Comment: To clarify even further, B cannot exist without A. So when adding both in a single transaction, it is reasonable to put the database code inside `dataLayerForObjectA.class`? If there's no other possible answers, I guess I will try this approach first, and update on my progress.

Comment: Don't mind if I also like to take this opportunity to clarify about `Service` layer. It is much more flexible than the database layer since it doesn't model after objects right? So if I have a `User` object which has a field `accountType`, I could have different services for it such as `adminService`, `normalUserService`, but I can't do this for database layer since it is modelled after objects it should fetch?

Comment: @DxHito If this does answer your question then you should accept.